# Streambuilder in Flutter for Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend, stream-builder, customscrollview

Hi i am a newbie in flutter and I am trying to fetch data from the firestore using a stream builder and display a spinner while the data is being fetched from the firebase database. I tried implementing a stream builder and future builder. I have a function that fetches the data from the firestore and i then pass the data into another function to populate the silver grid. Can someone please help me?

```
getDevotions(DevotionNotifier d) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('devotions').getDocuments();

    List<devotion> _devotionList = [];

    snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
      devotion d1 = devotion.fromMap(document.data);
      _devotionList.add(d1);
    });

    d.devotionList = _devotionList;
  }
}
```

```
class _dailyDevotionPageState extends State<dailyDevotionPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    DevotionNotifier _devotionNotifier =
        Provider.of<DevotionNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    getDevotions(_devotionNotifier);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DevotionNotifier _devotionNotifier = Provider.of<DevotionNotifier>(context);
    getDevotions(_devotionNotifier);

    String url = "https://picsum.photos/412/700";

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 220.0,
              pinned: true,
              elevation: 50,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                title: Text(
                  'Devotional',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Merriweather',
                  ),
                ),
                background: Image.asset(
                  'assets/2.jpg', // <===   Add your own image to assets or use a .network image instead.
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                childAspectRatio: 0.7,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  int i = _devotionNotifier.devotionList.length - index - 1;

                  return devotionLayout(_devotionNotifier, i, context);
                },
                childCount: _devotionNotifier.devotionList.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What stops working? Please be more specific. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited the question a bit to elaborate the problem i am having.

Comment: Are you checking if you are receiving the data on your stream snapshot?

Comment: Yeah i checked there is no data coming from the snapshot

Comment: Then you need to fix that first. Figure out why the query you are doing is not valid. Only you have access to your Firebase to test it.

Comment: oh okay thanks for your help

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have issues with fetching data from the collection that you've set. You can revisit the Firestore [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) on fetching all documents in a collection and see if you have skipped any in your setup.

Fetching the collection should look similarly like this.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('devotions')
    .get().then((querySnapshot) {
  for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
    print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()}');
    // Assign the object from the snapshot to your List
  }
});
```